# No output in EditText. Why?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CheckBox yes = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.yes);
            CheckBox no = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.no);
            EditText ageText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ageText);
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            int age;
            age = 0;

            if (yes.isChecked()) {
                editText3.setText(age + 15);
            } else if (no.isChecked()) {
                editText3.setText(age - 10);
            }
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

This code is not giving me any output in editText3. Why this is happening? The code has no bugs but still no output!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrongly used **setOnClickListener**. Change your code this way:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
        if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
            //check age is string or not.if not a string means change into String format
            editText3.setText(age + 15);
        } else if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
            editText3.setText(age - 10);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for help but now i am facing another error (have a look at code)

Comment: in your  coding  button.setOnClickListener used inside another  button.setOnClickListener..its completly wrong...please refer basics concept of button click event

Comment: refer here for button event http://startandroid.ru/en/lessons/complete-list/210-lesson-9-event-listeners-with-button-example.html

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
button.setOnClickListener(new)onClickListener() ...
```

to

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

        if (checkBox.isChecked()){
            editText3.setText(age+15);
        } else if (checkBox.isChecked()){
            editText3.setText(age - 10);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with your problem. Update your post with the new error & logs.

Comment: You're probably missing curly braces in your code; it seems to be wrongly formatted.

Comment: ` int age;
                          age = 0 ;



                        if (yes.isChecked()) {
                            editText3.setText(age + 15);
                        } else if (no.isChecked()) {
                            editText3.setText(age - 10);
                        }
                     finish();


                    }`


**why it is not giving me any output ? **